# Parse.com import appcelerator ACS database

Tags: parse-platform, appcelerator, acs

I'm currently working on a app, which has been build by another company already. 
They build it on Appcelerator ACS (arrowDB) but when testing the queries are just too slow, where the same query on Parse.com is twice as fast.

So i'm trying to check how much work it is to put the existing database to parse.com but remain a functional app.

It's including users and quite a lot of custom objects and linkings.

It there anyone who moved from ACS to Parse?
If so, how was your process and are there things worth mentioning?

Comment: We'd be interested to learn which queries were slower for you and where you are based. Our (soon to be migrated) community ACS servers could be slower, but our new ArrowDB servers should come in at ~50ms.

Comment: Hi Fokke,

Basicly just a cloud object call
(see below) 
Same data in parse has a average of 400ms befor it's done loading 100 objects
In Appcelerator it can also get as low as 400ms but it varies many times to even 2000+ ms.


`Alloy.Globals.Cloud.Objects.query({
    classname : 'ads',
    limit : 15,
    order : '-created_at',
    response_json_depth : 4,
    where : {
     active : true,
     '$and' : [{
      groups : {
       '$in' : group
      },
      user_id : {
       '$in' : _chunk
      }
     }]
    }
   }`

Comment: Where are you based? And is it a legacy community ACS instance or of former enterprise now arrowDB?

Comment: Based in the netherlands. And i assume its the last it got changed to arrow from your old setups. Running on team setup appcelerator.

Comment: Yes, if you're on an Appcelerator Team plan then it'll be the new one. I'm in NL as well, so I'll see if I can debug this. Thx!

Comment: could you drop me a mail@fokkezb.nl so we can exchange some info that enables me to analyse the slow response?